# scale a number between a range

Tags: normalization, scales

I have been trying to achieve a system which can scale a number down and in between two ranges. I have been stuck with the mathematical part of it.

What im thinking is lets say number 200 to be normalized so it falls between a range lets say  0 to 0.66 or 0.66 to 1 or 1 to 1.66. The range being variable as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the (theoretical) minimum and maximum of the original values? Or can we use the entire range of available values to obtain these values (e.g. would you accept a max(x) and min(x) in 'the maths')?

Comment: yes, That would involve a couple of additional loops but can be found.

Comment: There are many more duplicates.  Here's a search: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normalize+range+is%3Aanswer+score%3A1.

Comment: There are many duplicates with the WRONG answers.....

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Your scaling will need to take into account the possible range of the original number. There is a difference if your 200 could have been in the range [200,201] or in [0,200] or in [0,10000].

So let

- $r_{\text{min}}$ denote the minimum of the range of your measurement
- $r_{\text{max}}$ denote the maximum of the range of your measurement
- $t_{\text{min}}$ denote the minimum of the range of your desired target scaling
- $t_{\text{max}}$ denote the maximum of the range of your desired target scaling
- $m\in[r_{\text{min}},r_{\text{max}}]$ denote your measurement to be scaled

Then

$$ m\mapsto \frac{m-r_{\text{min}}}{r_{\text{max}}-r_{\text{min}}}\times (t_{\text{max}}-t_{\text{min}}) + t_{\text{min}}$$

will scale $m$ linearly into $[t_{\text{min}},t_{\text{max}}]$ as desired.

To go step by step,

1. $ m\mapsto m-r_{\text{min}}$ maps $m$ to $[0,r_{\text{max}}-r_{\text{min}}]$.
2. Next,
   $$ m\mapsto \frac{m-r_{\text{min}}}{r_{\text{max}}-r_{\text{min}}} $$

   maps $m$ to the interval $[0,1]$, with $m=r_{\text{min}}$ mapped to $0$ and $m=r_{\text{max}}$ mapped to $1$.
3. Multiplying this by $(t_{\text{max}}-t_{\text{min}})$ maps $m$ to $[0,t_{\text{max}}-t_{\text{min}}]$.
4. Finally, adding $t_{\text{min}}$ shifts everything and maps $m$ to $[t_{\text{min}},t_{\text{max}}]$ as desired.

Comment: Great explanation! I'm in a scenario, where I want to minimize $m$ and want $m$ to take the value of $t_\text{min}$ if $m=r_\text{max}$ and to take the value of $t_\text{max}$ if $m=r_\text{min}$.
Thanks to your explanation, this was easy to achieve: Simply swap the numerator to $r_\text{min} - m$ and add $t_\text{max}$ instead of $t_\text{min}$ in the end:
$$ m\mapsto \frac{r_{\text{min}}-m}{r_{\text{max}}-r_{\text{min}}}\times (t_{\text{max}}-t_{\text{min}}) + t_{\text{max}}$$

Comment: Is there a formal name that describes this equation?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell: I have only ever seen it referred to as "we scaled variable $x$ to the interval $[a,b]$", where $r_{\text{min}}$ and $r_{\text{max}}$ are implicitly understood to be the minimum and maximum observed values of $x$.

Comment: is it somehow possible to get a new scaled value for two same m values?

Comment: @kuldeep: scaling is a *function*. A function will always map identical inputs to identical outputs. You are probably looking for something else.

Answer (score 49):

In general, to scale your variable $x$ into a range $[a,b]$ you can use:
$$
x_{normalized} = (b-a)\frac{x - min(x)}{max(x) - min(x)} + a
$$