# Standard error of mean of normalized scaled data

Tags: normalization

I  had to normalize my data using this equation :

$m ↦ (m - r_{min}) / (r_{max} - r_{min}) * (t_{max} - t_{min}) + t_{min}$

as seen here:  [scale a number between a range](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281162/scale-a-number-between-a-range)

If I calculate the  mean of these data and I want then to calculate the standard error, how do i do?

Do I only take into account the multiplication/division? when I do the standard error with the data taking into account only multiplication/division factor (m/(rmax-rmin)*(tmax-tmin))  I end up with negative values and have a bigger standard error in comparison to the value I have  with raw data.

Could someone help me  with this please?

Best Jean

Comment: Calculate this intervals at the original domain and then transform those estimates using your equation at hand.

Comment: @usεr11852 How do you propose to incorporate the potentially *very large* contribution to the standard error introduced by the uncertainties in the extreme values of the data?

Comment: @whuber Same way we would do it in any other case. As the OP realises, calculating SE in a bounded domain is messy (values outside the expected support) so using the unbounded original domain is the way to go. Is there something else *you* would do? :)

Comment: @usεr11852 My point is that the $r_{min}$ and $r_{max}$ are *random variables,* not constants.  I would consider that with great care!